# how to repeat the above plot with only two months data

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
a <-4
b<- 1
c<-0
set.seed(1)
wheat <- rnorm(128,a,b)
hazelnut <- runif(128, min = -4, max = 1)
corn <- rnorm(128,c,b)
DAY <- seq(as.Date("2018-03-01"),as.Date("2018-07-06"),by="day")
df<- data.frame(wheat,hazelnut,corn,DAY)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=wheat,y=DAY)) + geom_point(color="orange")
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=hazelnut,y=DAY)) + geom_point(color="blue")
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=corn,y=DAY)) + geom_point(color="red")
```

how to repeat the above plot with only two months data.
I did plot with all data but I can't make a plot only 2 months with previous plots.

Comment: @TomHoel the data is shared reproducibly. I don't think `dput()` will add anything here.

Comment: Do you want to show the last two months or the first two months?

Comment: Perhaps `ggplot(data=df[df$DAY >= max(df$DAY) - 60, ], aes(x=wheat,y=DAY)) + geom_point(color="orange")`, which will subset the incoming data `df` to only include `DAY` values within 60 days of the last day value.

Comment: Or if you're doing multiple plots like this, you could define `df2 <- df[df$DAY >= max(df$DAY) - 60, ]` and then reference df2 instead of df for each plot.

Comment: @jonSpring yes I do

Comment: @JonSpring I will use and answer to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(lubridate)
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(month = month(DAY)) %>%  
  filter(between(month, 3, 4)) %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  aes(wheat, DAY) + 
  geom_point()
```

Together:

```
df %>%  
  gather(-DAY, key = "type", value = "value") %>% 
  mutate(month = month(DAY)) %>%
  filter(between(month, 3, 4)) %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  aes(value, DAY) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ type, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: But your code doesn't work because of month command.

Comment: @MustafaYusufAksoy Oh sorry, you will need lubridate package